# Image is cut when device it's rotated using a slide show with timer

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, ios8, slideshow

I've developed a slide show using a UIScrollView and I have implemente a NSTimer to change the images automatic in a lapse of time in the following way :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
      ...
      isLandscape = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation.isLandscape
      NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(4, target: self, selector: Selector("updateScrollView"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

The method to call in change :

```
func updateScrollView(){

    var offsetX = scrollView.contentOffset.x

    if (self.isLandscape!){
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: offsetX + 1024, y: 0), animated: true)            
    }
    else{
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: offsetX + 768, y: 0), animated: true)            
    }
}
```

I create a variable named `isLandscape` to know when the device is in portrait or landscape and in base of this know how much to sum to the `contentOffset`.

But for some reason if I rotate the device in the precise moment that the timer it's called the image don't advance correctly to the next one, we can see one part of the previous and one part of the next, of course if I move it wiht my finger all it back to work.

How can I avoid the rotation if the timer it's called in this moment?
Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop (invalidate) the timer when rotation begins, and start it again (create a new one) when rotation has ended. Your view controller gets events that tell you when rotation will start and when it has ended.

(Another possibility: simply detect that rotation has ended and call `updateScrollView` then and there, to force the next slide in case we are in the "stuck" position. But I think my first suggestion is probably better.)

Comment: How I invalidate the timer?

Comment: You can't because you have foolishly failed to keep a reference to it. Once you have kept a reference to it, you tell it to `invalidate`. Please read the docs.

Comment: Yes you're right , just reference the timer and in the `viewWillTransitionToSize` invalide the timer and then I load again. Thanks good answer